# Download zoom image from amazon

Tags: download, album-art

My Granddad bought a vinyl record way back in 1950's many years have passed but my granddad is no longer with us but we have that LP. Now somehow I managed to rip that LP in mp3 format but I like the LP cover so much (he loved it too) so I want to keep it but imagine how it looks now! However I caught upon the same cover [at amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00BK3K4XY) but I don't want to use the 300x300 preview cover and want the zoom image. Can anyone look over the image and tell step-by-step on how to download it?

Comment: Are you just asking for the [source picture?](http://z2-ec2.images-amazon.com/R/1/a=B00BK3K4XY+c=A17SFUTIVB227Z+d=_SCR(0,0,0)_+o=01+s=RMTILE+va=MAIN+ve=375055820+e=.jpg)

Comment: Yes I am but How did you get it? View page source, Ctrl+F then what?

Comment: I got the source in chrome by going to downloaded resources after zooming in all the way - was presented with source http://z2-ec2.images-amazon.com/R/1/a=B00BK3K4XY+c=A17SFUTIVB227Z+d=_SCR(3,0,0)_+o=01+s=RMTILE+va=MAIN+ve=375055820+e=.jpg under resources for the object and adjusted it to http://z2-ec2.images-amazon.com/R/1/a=B00BK3K4XY+c=A17SFUTIVB227Z+d=_SCR(0,0,0)_+o=01+s=RMTILE+va=MAIN+ve=375055820+e=.jpg

Comment: I still don't get it would you be able to explain with steps & pictures (if you don't mind) please?

Comment: Plus answer select **Answer the question** at the bottom so I can check it.

Comment: @kurast - Bless you!  That is much better!  I thought this question looked familiar.  I'm pretty sure it is the one I used in the example. :-)  BTW, feel free to keep going.  You're on a roll.

Comment: @fixer1234 this is the one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a partial answer as I cannot confirm if there is a higher res image on the amazon servers but giving this solution at the request of OP

---

**Required tools**

Google Chrome

---

*Step 1)*

You need to select the option `See larger image (with zoom)` on the page referenced by OP

*Step 2)*

You will then need to zoom in as much as Amazon will allow you to then right-click the page and select `Inspect element`

*Step 3)*

Go to the resource tab in your Developer Tools window and find the image resource that matches the image in the Amazon window

[image: Amazon webpage / Dev tools]

*Step 4)*

No we will have the URL

```
http://z2-ec2.images-amazon.com/R/1/a=B00BK3K4XY+c=A17SFUTIVB227Z+d=SCR(3,0,0)_+o=01+s=RMTILE+va=MAIN+ve=375055820+e=.jpg
```

We want to change the value under `d=SCR(3,0,0)` to `d=SCR(0,0,0)` and reconstruct it to look like

```
http://z2-ec2.images-amazon.com/R/1/a=B00BK3K4XY+c=A17SFUTIVB227Z+d=_SCR(0,0,0)_+o=01+s=RMTILE+va=MAIN+ve=375055820+e=.jpg
```

*Step 5)*

Now just open the new link in a browser and you will have a higher res version of the image to look at

---

**Foot notes**

- This guide was purely written so OP can view the higher resolution image
- I will not be providing steps in other browsers as I'm unfamiliar with other browsers in comparison to Google Chrome